# Is it possible to glue from 100-gon ( gluing sides by pairs) to get a surface of the 42 genes

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Is it possible to glue from 100-gon ( gluing sides by pairs) to get a surface of the a) 42 genus b) with 2 genus

My ideas - to use Euler formula

Comment: Does OP possibly mean a surface of genus $42$ or $2$?

Comment: You can easily get genus $2$ by reading the word $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ followed by cancelling pairs $aa^{-1}bb^{-1}\ldots$.

Comment: For genus $42$ the vertices of the $100$-gon would have to fall into $17$ equivalence classes, if I did the calculation correctly, but off the top of my head I don't see an obstruction to it working.

Comment: The euler characteristic is $2-2g=V-E+F$. Actually I see I made a mistake now. $F=1$ and $E=50.$ (I was thinking $E=100$.) So $2-2*42=V-50+1$. So $-33=V$ which is impossible. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Genus 42 is impossible because $V-E+F=2-2g$. We know that $F=1$ and $E=50$ because the $100$ boundary edges are identified in pairs. Working this out yields $V=-33$ which is not possible.

Genus $2$ is possible. Just start with the normal presentation of genus $2$: $(xyx^{-1}y^{-1}ztz^{-1}t^{-1})$ followed by a bunch of cancelling pairs of the form $aa^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, there was typo. Should be a $t^{-1}$ on the end. The $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ gives you a torus, so you need another one to get a genus $2$ surface.